# Change cache control directive for stale responses in Varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

This is my first time experimenting with Varnish.

We noticed our CDN not doing any request coalescing, so as an experiment I'm allowed to try out Varnish.

However I can't seem to figure out how to modify the response headers when stale content is served.

Image the following `vcl` and all backend responses have `max-age=60, public, s-maxage=600` as the cache-control directive.

```sh
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 3600s;
    return (deliver);
}
```

When I:

- visit `/foo`
- do a varnish soft purge and a subsequent CDN (hard) purge on `/foo`
- visit `/foo` again

When visiting `/foo` for the second time I'll immediately get a (stale) response. However I don't want it to have the same cache-control directive anymore, because then my CDN will continue to serve this stale response for another 10 minutes.

Is it possible to change the cache-control directive for stale content to `max-age=0, public, s-maxage=10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the VCL code you need to modify the `Cache-Control` header for stale content:

```
vcl 4.1;

sub vcl_deliver {
    //set resp.http.x-ttl = obj.ttl;
    //set resp.http.x-grace = obj.grace;
    if(obj.ttl <= 0s && obj.grace > 0s ) {
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=0, public, s-maxage=10";
    } 
}
```

> If you want to debug the process, just uncomment the 2 lines and look for the `x-ttl` and `x-grace` response headers to see the remaining values for both timers.

Although you can control the staleness by setting `beresp.grace` in VCL, you can also set the staleness through the `stale-while-revalidate` directive in the `Cache-Control` header.

Here's an example:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public, s-maxage=600, stale-while-revalidate=3600
```

This will allow the browser to cache for a minute, allow intermediary servers to cache for 10 minutes and set an allowed staleness of an hour while revalidating outdated content.